Shopware 6.5 - Transactional mail testing - Workflow + Tools?
What is a preferably automated way to create transactional mails and test them with different sets of data?
Speaking of the admin panel UI (Settings -> Email templates), I have some trouble understanding what an efficient workflow can be.

Priority is a good preview and email testing feature, which seems to be lacking without extensions.


Questions
1. How do I send test mails (e.g., order confirmation) for a specific order?
It seems that Shopware is using the latest order by default.
Sadly the preview and test sending don’t display all data and conditionals, so I’d prefer to give it a custom order ID along the way.
Seems to be somewhere between the Vue app and API abstraction, but that exceeds my current backend knowledge. Should I try to override or extend the request?
2. What tools/ plugins are recommended for better email workflows?
I know ‘FroshTemplateMail’ for templating. However, it’s ignored from the preview and test send feature.
How would I test my mails with the plugin?
3. Can TWIG translations be used in email templates?
It seems not to be the case, as I’ve found texts hard-coded. Translation and other features like dump() seem to not work in email templates.
So should I then copy the template and manually translate each?
4. Could I leverage Flows to simplify sending transactional emails for tests?
As far as I see it, it doesn't seem suited for this out of the box.
5. Automate test order process for fully functioning emails?
Should I use Selenium/ Webdriver to automate test orders, or choose an API approach?
I can imagine that this would result in better test emails than I get from the admin.
6. What extensions or 3rd party service integrations would you recommend?
Anything free or commercial is welcome as suggestion.

Why do I want this?
In a project, I have 55 email templates in 5 languages, which gives 275 variants.
Editing these manually would be a laborious and expensive process. I’d like to optimize every possible bit of it, instead of spending a week or so hard-coding texts or clicking through the website to create test orders that result in test mail. :)

Thank you for any help!
